# Is there a way to play audio with the screen off or in background on an app in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, background-process

I have been looking for a way to have audio/music play on an app if the screen is either off or the user is not on the mobile tab of the app.

At first I tried to mess with some audio settings, then I tried looking into some of the project settings. I found some settings relating to running in background, but none of those solved the problem.

Even just a C# script that can go with Unity's audio system to play it with out being on would help if I found it.

Comment: I think using Unity alone the answer is no. Check these two links might give you an idea
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/197908/how-to-play-audio-in-unity-when-a-mobile-game-runs-in-the-background-or-the-scre
https://forum.unity.com/threads/running-audio-in-background.244847/

Comment: @Yugerten Awesome, thanks. I saw the forum.unity.com thread a while ago when browsing some different options, but now actually reading it I have a better understanding of how it all works.